# fragment.setView(frame,this); not working in Processing Android example

Tags: android-studio, processing

I am currently working with android studio and processing.

When I put the code shown [here](https://android.processing.org/tutorials/android_studio/index.html), I have two errors. The first one: `fragment.setView(frame, this);`, where the function seems not to exist. The second one is importing `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity`, where it doesn't exist, but I am not afraid of.

Can anybody help me?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
    frame.setId(CompatUtils.getUniqueViewId());
    setContentView(frame, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    sketch = new Sketch();
    PFragment fragment = new PFragment(sketch);
    fragment.setView(frame,this);                    //HERE IS THE ERROR
    }
```